# Execute Powershell command from script path

Tags: powershell

First I will give a brief overview of what im trying to achieve. I want to go through a series of HTML files, replace code and then re-save these HTML files. This all works however the PS command will only execute this on HTML files which are on the default Powershell path (for me this is the H drive).

I want to be able to have a seperate folder which contains my powershell script and HTML files and convert them in that folder NOT from the H drive.

The code I have is follows:

**Powershell script**

```
$HTMLfiles=get-childitem . *.html -rec
foreach ($files in $HTMLfiles)
{

(Get-Content $files.PSPath) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "this text", "TEST" } | Set-Content $files.PSPath

}
```

This successfully changes all HTML files on the H drive that contain the words 'this text' with 'TEST'. I want to be able to change these HTML files from where the Powershell script is located, NOT from the H drive?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in variable called `$PSScriptRoot` to retrieve the files from the same folder where the PowerShell script resides.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Include *.HTML;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Im getting slightly confused. Where exactly do I use this code and wouldnt I have to change the PSPath to resave these HTML files to the same folder as the powershell script?

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite understanding you. Let me ask it in the form of a question: Do you want to: 1) Put PowerShell script in a local folder, 2) Copy files from H drive to the same folder as the script file, 3) manipulate the HTML files in that local folder?

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you ask to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to look for items in the current directory, to make the script look for files in another directory, you just have to specify it to Get-ChildItem :

```
$HTMLpath="C:\path\to\your\html\files"
$HTMLfiles=get-childitem $HTMLpath *.html -rec
foreach ($files in $HTMLfiles)
{

(Get-Content $files.PSPath) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "this text", "TEST" } | Set-Content $files.PSPath
}
```

Edit : 
if you want the path to be passed as an argument to your script, just do the following :

```
param($HTMLpath)
$HTMLfiles=get-childitem $HTMLpath *.html -rec
foreach ($files in $HTMLfiles)
{

(Get-Content $files.PSPath) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "this text", "TEST" } | Set-Content $files.PSPath
}
```

then you can call your script in the console (assuming you are in the directory where your script is) : `./myscript "C:\path\to\your\files"`

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Can I ask how could I set the HTMLpath to the path of the Powershell file? instead of having to specify it in the code

Comment: Im sorry I dont think I explained myself very well. I want to be able to get the execution path of the script, find and replace text in the HTML files that are in the same folder of the script and resave them in that same folder. I dotn want to have to specify the path to the HTMl files, they are in the same folder as the script. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Get-ChildItem . *.html -Rec` will get all files under the current working directory. If you happen to be in the same folder as your script when you call it, I'd expect it to work as you want. If you call the script from another path, e.g. by setting up a scheduled task to run `powershell.exe <path_to_script>` then it may not pick up the files you want. Maybe H: is the root of your Windows user profile?

As per other answers, using `$PSScriptRoot` or passing the path under which the .html files reside in a parameter would be good. To combine both, you can add a parameter to your script AND set the default value for that parameter to be `$PSScriptRoot`:

```
param($HTMLpath = $PSScriptRoot)
```

This will (1) allow you to specify a remote path if necessary and (2) otherwise default to the path where the script is saved.